# Why is my system running python2 despite all my efforts to run python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I'm having trouble running a script downloaded from an Android repository. Based on related questions and on my own testing, I'm pretty sure that the problem is that it's being interpreted by Python2, when it was written for Python3.

Here's my attempt at reproducing the problem in a script of my own:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# test.py
import sys
print('hello', file=sys.stderr)
```

And here are the test steps:

```sh
$ alias python=python3
$ python --version
Python 3.6.9
$ python test.py
hello
$ unalias python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
$ python test.py
  File "test.py", line 5
    print('hello', file=sys.stderr)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's confusing is that, while *this* test executes as expected, when I use `repo` to attempt to install Android Open Source Project, I get the `SyntaxError` (from essentially an identical line of script), despite running `alias python=python3`. (The shebang doesn't seem to affect the test or the main script.)

What am I missing? How can I run this script using the correct version of python3? And assuming there is a workaround, how do I clean up afterwards so that the rest of my system can still access python2 when it wants to?

Comment: You can add `alias python=python3` to your `~/.profile`.

Comment: What is `repo`? If it's a script and it has `python` in its shebang, try changing it to `python3`. On the other hand, what OS are you using? For example, [Ubuntu 20.04+ has the package `python-is-python3`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031733/301745) to change the system `python` executable version.

Comment: @DYZ Aliases don't affect scripts or other executables. See [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66662359/4518341).

Comment: The irony here is that the parse error actually comes from a block of script whose job is to detect the Python version and inform the user that this particular script requires Python 3. The user will never see that message, though, because the script requires Python 3.

Comment: @wjandrea it turns out that `repo` is indeed a python script, taking advantage of linux's extensionless nature to look like a regular executable. And it did indeed have the plain `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang at the top. But changing that to python3 doesn't stop the error coming up when parsing `main.py`. I'm only running ubuntu 18.04 so I don't have the newer package. I think I need to look further at (potentially) all the scripts that might run

Comment: I seem to have got around the problem by, instead of running `repo init -options ...`, specifying `python3 /path/to/repo init -options ...`
I'm not sure if this solution is too simple, but it's got me past this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alias` only changes the interpretation of commands you directly type into your shell. `repo` is therefore unaffected, because it doesn't type the python command into your shell.

Usually the best way to run a different Python configuration from the system's is to use virtualenvs.

Comment: A virtualenv seems like a rather daunting solution. Also, from my initial research, it sounds like anything that I download or install from within that virtual environment would not be usable from outside it. Does that sound right to you? I think I really just want a temporary workaround to let me download and install the necessary repo(s) for AOSP

Comment: venv or another environment manager (conda is significantly heavier, but also popular) is definitely the right way to do this. then you can run repo from within an environment that has the correct version of python. resist patching systemwide - that PATH leads to the dark side.